# 2 questions about java code and android sdk

Tags: java, android

I have two questions:

1. Android has two orientations: horizontal and vertical. How can I set the screen to stay in  only the horizontal orientation or only the vertical orientation?
2. I have loadscreen with animation. How can I play a video while the application is loading?  (Like in the Gameloft games.)

Can anyone give me any examples please?

Answer (score 3):

In the future, you should only ask a single question per post.

I will address your first question here:

You can set the Orientation for an `Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` by using the [`android:screenOrientation`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) property.

I cannot tackle the second question as I haven't played any Gameloft games.

Comment: thx . http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxdZWhga0Vw - gameloft game , watch 10 seconds . gameloft games start with this video .

Answer (score 1):

As for playing videos: Android has a build-in [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html). In the API-Demos there is an example. The [activity](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html) for this example and the [layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/layout/videoview.html).

This should help you along. I think it's safe to say it would be appreciated if you did a bit more research in the future.